# Using fetch to obtain data from mongodb with express for react app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, fetch-api

So I am relatively new to programming, and I am trying to get a better grasp on how backend and front end connect and where they are supposed to connect, so that I can use it for future projects. So what I am curious about is, if you make a directory for front end and backend, where your front end is a react app, and a backend with an express api for CRUD operations on a mongodb database. For the react app, can I use a simple fetch request? If so, where should the url point to? Would it just be the domain name of the site (assuming the directory’s are hosted at the same place), or would you have to do something like the IP address of the server and then direct it to the express api? Any clarification would be appreciated :)

I tried to use mongodb’s api for authentication and database access, but I wasn’t getting the connection working, and I figured out what I was doing wrong, but as I have done more research I have realized I would like to do something more similar to the method above.

Comment: _"For the react app, can I use a simple fetch request?"_... yes. The rest of your question is a little broad and depends on how each app is running. You can send requests directly to the Express server but then you'll probably need CORS support. You could have Express serve the React app statically. Or you could keep them separate and use a reverse proxy to translate local requests to remote ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, for the react app, can I use a simple fetch request? It looks like you want to build a
local backend api where you make frontend requests from a react app. Assuming a backend with nodejs and express to then create api endpoints/routes(crud) seems a pretty good starting point to learn how a full stack app can be built.

backend: in the server side, define a basic node + express server instance that could listens on port:5000. Then, write a GET request to for ex. `/products` route that will return a list of products from a dummy list so you can test easily those endpoints before going into real database setup, like with mongodb or postgres.

frontend: On your react side, in a component, define a useEffect hook that will call a function that's using the fetch api, yes you can define a single api call by having a fetch function make a request call to your backend server, like:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:5000/products`)
```

Then once you get the response data from the backend, get ready to render the list of products in your jsx.
There are more than one possible environments to create a full stack app locally, but I suggest start with a simple api route and go from there by adding more endpoints and logging those responses in the browser, study different HTTP methods, like GET, POST, DELETE and don't be afraid to get those network errors, 404 or 500, the more you debug errors and get exposed to these network logs, the better you will be prepared to build more complex applications.

I strongly recommend you first show the community what you've researched until know and built by sharing code snippets or potential errors before so we know how to help better.

Further reading on:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch

Also research on CORS concepts(in one of these cases/local server setup, you need to define CORS Headers  Required for cross-origin/ cross-server communication) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: Awesome thank you! This helped clear some things up, and I’ll be sure to provide more context and code snippets for future questions, i’m a new user haha.